# How to do sonar analysis locally (pre-commit) for ant based java project and generate html/pdf report locally

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I have a ant java project , i am using sonar-runner to do the sonar analysis on this project . I have a central sonar server . I have configured central sonar server parameters in the sonar-project.properties file . So when i run sonar-runner it published the values (static analysis , code coverage , unit test results) into the central sonar dashboard

But i want to do the same analysis locally i.e without publishing the values into central sonar dashboard .
I want to generate a local (html/pdf) report by using the central sonar profile.

What is the best way to do this ? Any steps to perform this or links would be helpfull

Comment: This is a usecase that the Sonar Eclipse plugin is designed to solve. Rightly or wrongly the creators of Sonar assume that Sonar is run from ANT within a CI server like Jenkins.

Comment: I was looking for solution without using eclipse i.e i perform sonar analysis on command line using sonar-runner and wanted a report locally (like generating cobertura report [a html report] locally)